# Read uploaded file content

Tags: asp.net-core, angular8

can anybody help me to read uploaded file content ?
I am working with upload document in asp .net core, angular 8 and i ma able to upload and save into local disc.. I want to get the uploaded document content and it should show as a preview in angular.. how can i achieve this?
 typescript code to send uploaded file to server

```
public uploadFile = (files) => {
    if (files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

    this.http.post('https://localhost:44333/api/Quotation/Upload', formData, { reportProgress: true, observe: 'events' })
      .subscribe(event => {
        debugger
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
          this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.message = 'Upload success.';
          this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Did you try this code and got an error we can help you with? Please clarify where your problem is. SO is not a code factory but to help solving errors.

Comment: @Justlearnedit this is working fine.. but i want to get filename from the uploaded folder in asp .net core.. that i am unable to get.. This i have tried but not getting filename  public IActionResult GetFileUploads(string filename)
        {
            filename = "download.jpg";
            var path = @"D:\Uploads" + "\\" + filename;
            //var imageFileStream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            var imageData = File(path, "image/jpeg");
            return imageData;
        }

Comment: So did you get an error?

Comment: @Justlearnedit no error in server side

Comment: @Justlearnedit i need to list the uploaded document in angular and preview it so i need to get the filename

Comment: How to preview the contents of the uploaded file, you can refer to this link: https://w3path.com/new-angular-8-file-upload-or-image-upload/

Comment: @YongqingYu i cant use this  as i want to preview the document after uploading into local disc